# Prototype equivalent of JQuery's slice

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

What is the Prototype equivalent of this JQuery code?

```
$('.aCssClass tr>td').slice(1, -1).addClass('indent')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Prototype, you'd do something like this:

```
$$('.aCssClass tr>td').slice(1, -1).each(function(cell) {
  $(cell).addClassName('indent');
});
```

The "slice" method is part of JavaScript, but I have a vague recollection that it may not be there in some very old browsers. (Not sure about IE6 but I'll check.) (*edit* — according to MSDN you should be good for IE6; I don't have it available so I can't make sure :-)

Comment: I haven't worked with Prototype, but is the double-dollar (`$$('.aCssClass...')`) intentional?

Comment: Yup, this works: http://jsfiddle.net/WnQna/. And yes, @David Thomas. In Prototype, `$()` is an ID or element selector and `$$()` is a CSS selector.

Comment: Yes - "$$" does something fairly similar to the jQuery "$(selector)" variant.  The Prototype "$" function is a significantly different thing. The two libraries have some things in common but the fundamental ideas behind them are quite different. Prototype is (to me) about making *programming* more convenient, with a nod to DOM realities; jQuery is about making *DOM manipulation* more convenient, with a nod to programming realities.

Comment: Ah, thanks @Pointy and @Cory. Just the unfamiliar syntax threw me a little. Maybe because of the similarity of the selector in the enclosed text-string. =)

Answer (score 1):

It's even easier, since $$() returns extended elements:

```
$$('.aCssClass tr>td').slice(1, -1).invoke('addClassName', 'indent');
```